# How to redirect Woocommerce to a specific page?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I use "Woocommerce User Email Verification" which after the user registers, it redirects user to the main page. It doesn't have built in option to redirect users to a page where I can tell them that they should check their email and confirm it to access my-account section!

Plugin link: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-confirmation-email/

download link:
https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/woo-confirmation-email.3.1.15.zip

Please tell me how I can redirect a user after they press the Register to any page of my own website that I want?

Ps. I know that without this plugin, when user registers, they automatically go to my-account section. So this plugin is causing the Redirect I think.

Would you be so kind and help?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you want here? your question is not clear

Comment: in your plugin misc settings there is an option custom page , set your custom page there , it will show after verify the email and redirect

Comment: @dipmala
I want to redirect users after they press Register on Woocommerce page to the page that I want

Comment: @TechnoDeviser I wish there was an option. It doesn't work. 
Anyway I set all the options there to custom with no success when I registered.
https://pasteboard.co/Hpw1Pxw.png

Comment: this plugin works like this register->email->email verification link -> custom page redirect, but you want redirection after the user register.,,Am i right

Comment: for this you can add this code in function.php

Comment: function wpse_registration_redirect() {
    return home_url( '/my-page' );
}

add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'wpse_registration_redirect' );

Comment: @TechnoDeviser Yesss! That's exactly what I want. Please help.

Comment: @TechnoDeviser added your code. with "Woocommerce User Email Verification" turned on, it still goes to homepage. With "Woocommerce User Email Verification" deactivated, it goes to my-account. Please note I changes the slug to my own which is /emailverification

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in function.php

```
function wpse_registration_redirect() {
    return home_url().'/my-page' ;
}

add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'wpse_registration_redirect' );
```

or

```
function custom_registration_redirect() {
    return home_url().'/my-page' ;
}
add_action('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'custom_registration_redirect', 2);
```

or
After login

```
function admin_default_page() {
  return home_url().'/my-page' ;
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

or After WooCommerce login

```
function iconic_login_redirect( $redirect_to) {
    $redirect_to = 'http://yoursiteshop';
   return $redirect_to ;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'iconic_login_redirect',1100, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. still going to home page

Comment: change the '/my-page' to yours '/your-page-name' in both

Comment: Still going to the home page. :(

Comment: add wp_logout(); in custom_registration_redirect function before return

Comment: Thanks so much really. I just don't know where to put "or After login" & "or After WooCommerce login" codes. If these shoud go to functions.php too , they didn't work. 

About "add wp_logout(); in custom_registration_redirect function before return"
Shoud I still add wp_logout(); or not needed? Would you please edit that too? since when I put it I get 500 error.

Comment: I put wp_logout(); correctly but again redirected to home page

Comment: share website url

Comment: here it is : goo.gl/AwmE8x

I really appreciate your fast help. Thanks. This is running me crazy :((((

Comment: try last one only after woocommerce login once again

Comment: Should I put this in functions.php too? I did it and I got ERROR 500.

Comment: Thanks! The code didn't work but when I deactivated "Woocommerce User Email Verification" , and activated "woo-login-redirect ", it went to the page I wanted. Now I think if I remove the redirection to homepage from the plugin, it would work.

Comment: if you download the plugin and see "public" folder, there is a file. 
please check line 40 and 126. I know the problem lies there. .I just don't know how to edit. Please help

Comment: Any help? :(((:(((